# Removing unwanted XML at runtime

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file which is read and copied to a new XML file at runtime. 
Sometimes, the XML contains invalid XML , such as -

`</SST_DSS.TickerConfig>erConfig>`
Is there any way to 'clean' the xml before writing to the new XML file?
Currently I am writing to the new file like so...

```
string workingPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"C:\SST Software\DSC\Tickers\", currentTicker + ".tck");
string configString = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(workingPath);
File.WriteAllText(newFilePath, configString);
```

**How can I remove the 'erConfig' before writing to new XML file?**

Comment: You'd be guessing.  This looks like the source file wasn't truncated before it was overwritten, so I suggest you fix the writing of the file rather than trying to read an invalid file.

Comment: A XML file can only have on tag at the root level.  Combining the text doesn't remove the ending tag from first file nor the XML definition line and root tag from 2nd file.  You can use Regex to edit the file but this would be considered a kludge.  It is better to open the two xml files as xml documents and then combine the xml using xml methods.